# Ethernet Data Transfer rate

Tags: wireless-networking, data-transfer

I have a 4 MB leased line connection. If I check it directly, it shows 4 MB download and 4 MB upload.
In LAN network, I used to download 4 GB file and get only 500 KB/Sec download speed.

Is it relevant transfer rate or not?

Comment: Sounds like a piece of your hardware on the network has a slower LAN port.  Verify they all your equipment has the same speed LAN port.

Answer (score 1):

Your bandwidth is 4Mbps (bits per second)which correctly translates to a practical speed of maximum 512KB/s (bytes per second).

So 500 out of 512 is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are confused about mega-bits and mega-bytes.

LAN and line-speed are generally given in (mega/kilo)-**bits**/per second.
40000000 bits or 4000 K-bits in your case.
Tranfer-speed in an application is often given as (mega/kilo)-**bytes**/per second.
500 KBytes/s == 4000 K-Bits/s so this seems pretty much correct.

Please note:
- Computers usually reckon with binary kilos (1K = 1024), but network-speeds always use the normal metric unit for kilo (1K = 1000). This might cause some additional round-off errors, depending on which variant is used.
 - And there is also always some overhead for the networking protocols themselves so your raw data-transfer will usually be slightly lower than the theoretical maximum speed of the network itself.